# Looking for a better way of creating a new data.frame with purchase frequency information from another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Ok, this may come across a little convoluted, but I'll try and explain what I mean:

I have a data.frame that tells me the number of products in different categories that were sold at different sessions throughout each day of several years, and also give a True/False column for each product in each category that tells me if at least one of that type of product was sold within that session.

Here's a small example:

```
    Year    Month   Day Session  Number Sold  At Least One of X
    2014    1        15 19876         10         True
    2014    1        15 25698         10         False
    2014    1        15 2156           2         True
    2014    1        16 21578          0         False
    2014    1        16 1123          12         False
    2014    1        16 15469         25         True
    2014    1        16 32654          0         False
    2014    1        17 12589          8         True
    2014    1        18 54269          4         True
    2014    1        18 25136         14         True
```

So, for the first observation, there were 10 items in this category sold, and at least one of them was Product X.  There were 10 sold in the category in the next session, but none of them were Product X.

Here's a dput() for the above table:

```
structure(list(year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014), month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), day = c(15, 
15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18), session = c(19876, 25698, 
2156, 21578, 1123, 15469, 32654, 12589, 54269, 25136), numbsold = c(10, 
10, 2, 0, 12, 25, 0, 8, 4, 14), min1x = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("False", "True"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("year", 
"month", "day", "session", "numbsold", "min1x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, I'm making data.frames that show how the % of time that X is at least one of the products purchased within its category by day of the year.  I'm looking to get the following output:

```
      Date      Frequency Sold
    2014-01-15  0.6666667
    2014-01-16  0.5000000
    2014-01-17  1.0000000
    2014-01-18  0.5000000
```

With my extremely limited knowledge of R (I'm learning, but slowly), I know it can be done like so:

```
  myout<-data.frame(c("1/15/2014","1/16/2014","1/17/2014","1/18/2014"),
              c(sum(mydf$min1x=="True" & mydf$year==2014 & mydf$month==1 & mydf$day==15)
                /sum(mydf$numbsold > 0 & mydf$year==2014 & mydf$month==1 & mydf$day == 15)
              ,sum(mydf$min1x=="True" & mydf$year==2014 & mydf$month==1 & mydf$day==16)
                 /sum(mydf$numbsold > 0 & mydf$year==2014 & mydf$month==1 & mydf$day == 16)
              ,sum(mydf$min1x=="True" & mydf$year==2014 & mydf$month==1 & mydf$day==17)
                 /sum(mydf$numbsold > 0 & mydf$year==2014 & mydf$month==1 & mydf$day == 17)
              ,sum(mydf$min1x=="True" & mydf$year==2014 & mydf$month==1 & mydf$day==18)
                 /sum(mydf$numbsold > 0 & mydf$year==2014 & mydf$month==1 & mydf$day == 18)))
names(myout)<-c("Date","Frequency Sold")
myout$Date<-as.Date(myout$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Where I'm basically repeating commands and forcing it to build the data.frame one day at a time.  Of course, doing this over the course of two years and dozens of different products gets to be too much very quickly.

What can I use to tell R to build a data.frame for a particular product, showing the percentage of time that product made up at least one purchase within its category for each date found within the dataset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved well using the `data.table` package (which you'll have to install).

First create a date column out of the year, month, and day columns:

```
mydf$Date = as.Date(paste(mydf$year, mydf$month, mydf$day, sep="-"))
```

Then turn it into a `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
mydt = as.data.table(mydf)
```

Then you can perform this summarizing operation with:

```
mydt[, list(FrequencySold=mean(min1x[numbsold > 0] == "True")), by=Date]
```

Comment: `data.table` is definitely a way to go, however, your summarizing operation is not providing the output he desires.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName: Yep, took me a second to realize that (since fixed)

Comment: @iShouldUseAName and OP- both of your solutions work well.  Thanks you.  Are they simply two ways to do the same thing (as seems common in R)...i.e. is there an advantage that y'all see to using one over the other?

Comment: @datahappy - They are two different ways to do the same thing.  I think, biasedly, that my solution would be superior in certain ways.  In particular, someone new to R will find the `plyr` package to be much easier to grasp and deploy more quickly than `data.table` as `data.table` has a very steep learning curve.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  That was my instinct, as well.  I've noticed plyr tends to to come up in solutions quite often, likely for that reason.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName you cannot seriously look at your solution and this one and claim that yours is easier to read/understand; @datahappy - `data.table` is generally going to be much faster and easier to read/write

Comment: You're the first person I've met who thinks `data.table` would be easier to learn than `plyr`.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName: As a side note, `data.table` tends to be considerably faster than plyr (on large data frames), though [dplyr](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/) is comparable in speed.

Comment: This is very true.  `plyr` is garbage on really large datasets.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName basic `data.table` expressions, as in this answer, are super easy to learn - all you need to understand is that `d[i, j, by = b]` is read as *take d, apply i, then compute j for each group b*; more advanced ones will have things like `.SD` or `.N` in them, which are easy to grasp once you understand the above.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(plyr)
df$min1x <- as.logical(df$min1x)
ddply(df[df$numbsold > 0, ], .(year, month, day), summarize, frequency=sum(min1x) / length(min1x) )
```

Where `df` is the `data.frame` you provided.  You will need to form the dates yourself.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't give the desired output either. It looks like he want to limit it to cases where `numbsold` isn't 0

Comment: Good call.  I'll make the change now.